# qInstallMessageHandler() does not return fileline, filename, functioname

Tags: qt, debugging, logging, qt5

I have qInstallMessageHandler() to gimme all logs to external file with mainly rownumber error, so I can seee where the error comes from:

```
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQml>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QTextStream>
#include "mssql.h"
#include "cryption.h"
#include "led.h"


void myMessageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg)
{
    QDateTime datatime = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
    QString formattedDateTime = datatime.toString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    QByteArray localMsg = msg.toLocal8Bit();
    const char *file = context.file ? context.file : "";
    const char *function = context.function ? context.function : "";

    QString txt;
    switch (type) {
        case QtDebugMsg:
            txt = QString("%1: Debug: %2, file: %3, line: %4, function: %5").arg(formattedDateTime).arg(localMsg.constData()).arg(file).arg(context.line).arg(function);
        break;
        case QtInfoMsg:
            txt = QString("%1: Info: %2, file: %3, line: %4, function: %5").arg(formattedDateTime).arg(localMsg.constData()).arg(file).arg(context.line).arg(function);
        break;
        case QtWarningMsg:
            txt = QString("%1: Warning: %2, file: %3, line: %4, function: %5").arg(formattedDateTime).arg(localMsg.constData()).arg(file).arg(context.line).arg(function);
        break;
        case QtCriticalMsg:
            txt = QString("%1: Critical: %2, file: %3, line: %4, function: %5").arg(formattedDateTime).arg(localMsg.constData()).arg(file).arg(context.line).arg(function);
        break;
        case QtFatalMsg:
            txt = QString("%1: Fatal: %2, file: %3, line: %4, function: %5").arg(formattedDateTime).arg(localMsg.constData()).arg(file).arg(context.line).arg(function);
        break;
    }
    QFile outFile("debug.log");
    outFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text);
    QTextStream ts(&outFile);
    ts.setCodec("UTF-8");
    ts << txt << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qInstallMessageHandler(myMessageHandler);

    qmlRegisterType<MSSQL>("MSSQL", 1, 0, "MSSQL");
    qmlRegisterType<LED>("LED", 1, 0, "LED");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    // Sets path for SQLite
    engine.setOfflineStoragePath(QDir::currentPath());

    return app.exec();
}
```

but the debug.log file looks like:

```
30.06.2020 10:11:03: Debug: Terminal DB Error: No INI File Found!, file: , line: 0, function: 
30.06.2020 10:11:16: Warning: QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'Terminal_DB_External' is still in use, all queries will cease to work., file: , line: 0, function: 
30.06.2020 10:11:16: Warning: QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'ANeT_DB' is still in use, all queries will cease to work., file: , line: 0, function: 
30.06.2020 10:11:16: Warning: QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'Terminal_DB_External' is still in use, all queries will cease to work., file: , line: 0, function: 
30.06.2020 10:11:16: Warning: QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'ANeT_DB' is still in use, all queries will cease to work., file: , line: 0, function: 
30.06.2020 10:11:16: Debug: Terminal DB Error_1: "Driver not loaded Driver not loaded", file: , line: 0, function:
```

any thoughts how to have mainly errorline so I can see where the error comes from? the filename would be also desired, but I can live without function name if its not possible.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagelogcontext.html): `"Note: By default, this information is recorded only in debug builds. You can overwrite this explicitly by defining QT_MESSAGELOGCONTEXT or QT_NO_MESSAGELOGCONTEXT"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information is no logged if you build in debug mode.
If you are using QtCreator as IDE you can change the build type with the menu shown with the project button in the taskbar at bottom left (fourth button from the bottom, the one with a display icon).
If you are using qmake from the command line do 'qmake CONFIG+="debug"'.
One thing to notice is that the debug message your are talking about come from the qt library itself, so in case you are doing things in a sort of standard way you are just fine, but if you are linking manually or with customs scripts bear in mind that information depends on whether you are linking to the 'debug' or 'release' version of qtlibs. The debug versions of QtLibs family are suffixed with a 'd'.